# Create a GIF with a large number of frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, gif

I try to generate a GIF file from a video.

The code looks good for a short video like 2-3 seconds, but when i have a big video, and  i generate a large number of frames the application will crashed with error : `Terminated due the memory error.` and `Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died`.

The application crashed at line :

```
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
```

Below you have code used for  GIF creation:

```
    NSTimer *timer= [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(makeScreenshot) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [timer fire];


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, fl  * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [timer invalidate];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

            self.activityIndicator.alpha=1;

        }];
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(CreateGif) withObject:nil];

        });

    });

///////////////////////////////
-(void)makeScreenshot{
        @autoreleasepool {
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rec afterScreenUpdates:YES];

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



        NSData* pictureData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);


            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            frameNumber++;
            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/frame%d.jpeg", documentsDirectory,frameNumber];

            [pictureData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        }
    }

    -(void)CreateGif{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^
                       {

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
        NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];


        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fileURL.path error:nil];

        NSUInteger kFrameCount = frameNumber ;

        NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{
                                         (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                                 (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0, // 0 means loop forever
                                                 }
                                         };
        NSDictionary *frameProperties;
        switch (speed) {
            case 5:
                frameProperties = @{
                                    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                            (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.02f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                            }
                                    };
                break;
            case 10:
                frameProperties = @{
                                    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                            (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.2f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                            }
                                    };
                break;
            case 15:
                frameProperties = @{
                                    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                            (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.15f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                            }
                                    };
                break;
            case 20:
                frameProperties = @{
                                    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                            (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.1f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                            }
                                    };
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }



        documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
        fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];

        CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeGIF, kFrameCount  , NULL);
        CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

        for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <=kFrameCount ; i++) {

            @autoreleasepool{
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/frame%d.jpeg", documentsDirectory,i];



                UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);

                }
        }

        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

            CFRelease(destination);

            NSLog(@"url=%@", fileURL);




                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
                                          {
                                              self.imgGIF.hidden=NO;
                                              self.imgGIF.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]];
                                              self.imgGIF.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
                                              [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                                                  self.activityIndicator.alpha=0;
                                                  self.shareView.alpha=1;
                                                  self.shareButton.hidden=NO;
                                                  self.BackButtonOutlet.hidden=NO;
                                                  self.backButtonIMage.hidden=NO;

                                              }];
                                              canShare=YES;

                                              [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(removeImages) withObject:nil];
                                          });
                       });







    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It's normal, because the size of the resulting gif image must be huge. You can try make a series of small gif, or decrease a resolution...

Comment: Series of small gif?  If i decrease resolution i lose more quality.

Comment: >Series of small gif?

For example 10 sec video = 10 gifs (1 sec by one file)

>If i decrease resolution i lose more quality

Try to compare sizes of 1 sec video and 1 sec gif, with same resolution. Also when you work with gif you should keep all data in memory in contrast to video

Comment: And how as unite all small gifs in a big one?

Comment: I just tried to make a jpg Conversion. Size of a jpg frame is 16kb and still crashed on memory warning.

Comment: jpg conversion may give you some additional seconds, but you can't resolve problem such way. The problem is that gif image have a huge size and you need keep all this volume in the memory. 
The only option I see - it's write our own gif creator/extractor which will  work with file system to have only some frames in memory in one time.

Comment: You can try investigate that project https://github.com/liyong03/YLGIFImage or search something similar. Probably it's works as I describe earlier.

Comment: This project is not only for displaying GIFs? Can you give me any code for "work with file system" , please? I didn't have something similar before and i don't know how can i implement your idea.

Comment: I have no such code, it's just the advice how it might work. And I'm, even, not sure it will.